# winjs picture file size

Tags: javascript, windows, winjs

I'm trying to get the size (pixel, bites) from a picture in a Win 8 app. I pick the file with the openPicker and I get the file. But I can't find the size attributes? 
I'll display an error, if the file is to large.
Any idea how I can get this info?
Thanks.

Comment: Where are you trying to get them from specifically? You'll need to open the file and convert it to an image to get the width and height.

Comment: I get the file with the file picker from local storage.

Comment: You don't need to open the file for this--see my full answer below. Width, height, and size (as well as thumbnails and much more) are all available as metadata through the StorageFile object. Loading the whole file for this purpose just incurs lots of unnecessary memory overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this information through the StorageFile object itself, without having to open the file or load it into memory.

For convenience, let's say myFile is the StorageFile in question.

For image dimensions, call [myFile.properties.getImagePropertiesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.getimagepropertiesasync.aspx), the result of this is an [ImageProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.imageproperties.aspx) object that contains width and height properties. You can find an example of retrieving ImageProperties in the [Simple imaging sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-Imaging-Sample-a2dec2b0), scenario 1.

For the file size, call [myFile.getBasicPropertiesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getbasicpropertiesasync.aspx). The result is a [BasicProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.basicproperties.aspx) object whose size property has that value.

Answer (score 0):

After some more hours of searching and trying I've solved it like this:

```
//add picture
        document.getElementById("btnAddImg").addEventListener('click', function () {
            // Create the picker object and set options
            var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.viewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.thumbnail;
            openPicker.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.picturesLibrary;
            openPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll([".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"]);
             openPicker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(function (file) {
                file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.read).done(function (stream) {
                    var fileType = file.contentType;
                    var blob = MSApp.createBlobFromRandomAccessStream(fileType, stream);
                    var fdata = new FormData();
                    fdata.append('upload_field', blob);
                    //more code....
                });
             });
        });
```

Hope it helps some others.